# Polar representation of continuous curve.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Given a continuous curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Bbb R^2$ with $\gamma(t)\ne(0,0)^T$, can I always find continous functions $\rho:[a,b]\to\Bbb [0,\infty)$ and $\theta:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ so that $\gamma(t)=\rho(t)(cos(\theta(t)),sin(\theta(t)))^T$ ?. Do these functions have the same smoothness properies as $\gamma$?

Thanks

Comment: What about $\gamma(t) = (t,0)$ near $0$ ?

Comment: alright, thanks. So I would have to require the curve not to go through the origin?

Comment: In that case it is true. If you don't suppose $\gamma$ smooth, you can prove the result locally dividing $[a,b]$ in subintervals such that $\gamma$ doesn't leave a quarter of the plan, in that case such an angle $\theta$ is uniquely determined up to a constant. Then you just need to glue, taking the good constant.